# Datediff function of DQL is not returning results as expected 

Tags: sql, date, dql, documentum

I am trying to query documentum server using DQL query.  Using DATEDIFF function to select data that are created in the current date.  Here is the query

```
    SELECT title FROM content_table WHERE DATEDIFF(day, "r_creation_date", DATE(TODAY)) < '1' AND content_type IN ('story','news')
```

Problem is along with today's data its selecting yesterday's also. Why is less than 1 condition fetching yesterday's data also?

Have tried using DATEDIFF(day, "r_creation_date", DATE(TODAY)) = '0' but that does not fetch any result. I understand even the time comes into picture but as I am using 'day' as the date pattern will it not just calculate difference of the days alone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DATEDIFF+DQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT title FROM content_table WHERE r_creation_date > DATE(TODAY) AND content_type IN ('story','news')
```

if you need the objects created today (after 00:00, not in the last 24 h)

Answer (score 0):

I should use the `GETDATE()` function to get the current day

Regards.

Comment: SELECT title FROM content_table WHERE DATEDIFF(day, "r_creation_date", GETDATE()) < '1' AND content_type IN ('story','news') This is what i used. But its throwing query pass error at GETDATE method.

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder is r_creation_date a column  of content_table ? If so forget the quote and use content_table.r_creation_date